# How to read excel objects in Word template and convert to a table

Tags: vb.net

I have a word-template that contains a number of excel-objects. When running the program I'd like those objects to be automatically converted to Word-tables.

I've tried recording a macro, but that doesn't catch the opening of the excel-object and copying of the content. It does show the pasting into Word.

What's the way to go for this?

Comment: The question tag says `vb.net`. But using Word VBA is probably simpler since you are only missing the part that opens the Excel object. Is my understanding correct? You should also post some code that you have already tried.

Comment: @RobertBaron Bit late, but it turns out i misunderstood the task. I had to manually convert them and not automatically. Thanks though.